# What published metrics are there on how sci-fi is doing as a genre in the publishing business?

Tags: online-resources, publishing

I've heard that sci-fi is on the wane as a genre. Are there numbers to reassure me that sci-fi isn't going the way of Westerns/Cowboy books?

Answer (score 15):

[Locus](http://locusmag.com) magazine publishes a lot of statistics on books published in their annual year in review. The Feb. 2010 issue says that for original novels in 2009 there were:

- 232 SF
- 572 Fantasy
- 251 Horror

In 2001 there were:

- 251 SF
- 282 Fantasy
- 151 Horror

Overall for the last decade, SF has stayed fairly flat but is becoming a smaller percentage of the books published across all the related genres.

Answer (score 4):

Gardner Dozois publishes an anthology of short fiction every year:

- [The Year's Best Science Fiction: Twenty-Seventh Annual Collection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312608985)
- [The Year's Best Science Fiction: Twenty-Sixth Annual Collection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312551053)
- [and so on...](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_14?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=gardner+dozois&x=0&y=0&sprefix=gardner+dozois#/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_31?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=the+year%27s+best+science+fiction&sprefix=the+year%27s+best+science+fiction&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Athe+year%27s+best+science+fiction)

In each one, he has an essay summarizing major events in the field: books published, news about magazines or websites, deaths in the field, etc.  Without going back and re-reading the essays for recent years, my impression is that books and some websites are doing OK, magazines not so well.